# Composer create-project laravel memory error

Tags: php, macos, memory, laravel, fatal-error

I've installed composer, downloaded laravel and now try to create a project:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test_laravel --prefer-dist
```

But the answer is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar
```

Of course I googled it and the solution was to give it more memory through `php.ini`. I gave it 512M, 1G and even -1 and no way... Any suggestions?

Mac OS X 10.10.1 PHP 5.5.19

Comment: Try to run `composer self-update` and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install it through `Homebrew` it seems that [Composer package is not up to date](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2704#issuecomment-56364138).

If this is your case you can run from command line `composer self-update` and retry.